# Multi array quicksort in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I want to sort several arrays by one of these arrays with quicksort.
For testing I use the following data:

```
x    y        z
j    106.0    106
s    115.0    115
h    104.0    104
g    103.0    103
l    108.0    108
```

---

I already built a quicksort function for a single array which takes a `uint32_t data_type` value specifying the data type of the array to sort. In that special case sorting all arrays can be done with:

```
char x[5] = { 'j', 's', 'h', 'g', 'l' };
double y[5] = { 106.0, 115.0, 104.0, 103.0, 108.0 };
uint64_t z[5] = { 106, 115, 104, 103, 108 };
QuickSort(5, x, CHAR_NR);
QuickSort(5, y, DOUBLE_NR);
QuickSort(5, z, UINT64_NR);
```

`QuickSort` looks like:

```
void QuickSort(uint64_t arrlen, void *arr, uint32_t data_type)
```

It uses a switch on the `data_type` and calls functions like that:

```
static inline void quicksort_c(uint64_t arrlen, char *arr)
{
    if (arrlen < UINT64_C(2)) { return; }
    char p = arr[arrlen / UINT64_C(2)];
    char t;
    uint64_t i, j;
    for (i = UINT64_C(0), j = (arrlen - UINT64_C(1));; i++, j--) {
        while (arr[i] < p) { i++; }
        while (p < arr[j]) { j--; }
        if (i >= j) { break; }

        t = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = t;
    }
    quicksort_c(i, arr);
    quicksort_c(arrlen - i, arr + i);
    return;
}
```

---

Now I want a single function to be able to sort all arrays for cases where they would not have the order after sorting by one of the arrays. I follow a similar approach by using a switch on the `data_type` of the sorting array and specific functions for the different types. Instead of directly swapping two values it calles a function which loops through all arrays and swaps values:

```
char x[5] = { 'j', 's', 'h', 'g', 'l' };
double y[5] = { 106.0, 115.0, 104.0, 103.0, 108.0 };
uint64_t z[5] = { 106, 115, 104, 103, 108 };

uint32_t data_types[3] = { CHAR_NR, DOUBLE_NR, UINT64_NR };
void *arrs[3] = { x, y, z};
QuickSort_Multi(3, arrs, 5, data_types, 0, status);

...

static inline void quicksort_multi_c(uint64_t arrslen, void **arrs, 
    uint64_t arrlen, char *arr, uint32_t *data_types)
{
    if (arrlen < UINT64_C(2)) { return; }
    char p = arr[arrlen / UINT64_C(2)];
    //char t;
    uint64_t i, j;
    for (i = UINT64_C(0), j = (arrlen - UINT64_C(1));; i++, j--) {
        while (arr[i] < p) { i++; }
        while (p < arr[j]) { j--; }
        if (i >= j) { break; }
        quicksort_multi_swap(arrslen, arrs, data_types, i, j);
    }
    quicksort_multi_c(arrslen, arrs, i, arr, data_types);
    quicksort_multi_c(arrslen, arrs, arrlen - i, arr + i, data_types);
    return;
}

static inline void quicksort_multi_swap(uint64_t arrslen, void **arrs,
    uint32_t *data_types, uint64_t i, uint64_t j)
{
    char        buffer_c;
    uint64_t    buffer_u64;
    double      buffer_double;
    char        *buffer_c_arr;
    uint64_t    *buffer_u64_arr;
    double      *buffer_double_arr;

    uint64_t u64a;
    void *arr;
    for (u64a = UINT64_C(0); u64a < arrslen; u64a++) {
        arr = arrs[u64a];
        switch (data_types[u64a]) {
            case CHAR_NR:
                buffer_c_arr = arr;
                buffer_c = buffer_c_arr[i];
                buffer_c_arr[i] = buffer_c_arr[j];
                buffer_c_arr[j] = buffer_c;
                break;
            case UINT64_NR:
                buffer_u64_arr = arr;
                buffer_u64 = buffer_u64_arr[i];
                buffer_u64_arr[i] = buffer_u64_arr[j];
                buffer_u64_arr[j] = buffer_u64;
                break;
            case DOUBLE_NR:
                buffer_double_arr = arr;
                buffer_double = buffer_double_arr[i];
                buffer_double_arr[i] = buffer_double_arr[j];
                buffer_double_arr[j] = buffer_double;
                break;
            default:    break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Notice I didn't changed the quicksort algorithm itself. I just changed the swap function. Strangely with the above sample arrays I receive no compiler warnings but running the example creates a `segmentation fault`.
On the other hand it works with `char x[5] = { 'a', 'b', 'h', 'g', 'l' };`.

Any ideas how to solve that problem?

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. Use a single array of `struct`s with all fields.

Comment: What do you mean with XY problem?

Comment: XY Problem means you are solving the wrong thing. Instead of figuring out how to "tie" your arrays together, just put the data into a struct and sort it based on whatever field you want. The rest of the fields will be sorted along with it automatically.

Comment: Is google or your SO-search down? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem